# Cancel [self performSelector:... withObject:nil afterDelay:20];

Tags: xcode, ios4, iphone

I call method sr in viewDidLoad with below code,how can i cancel it before that method sr will call?

```
[self performSelector:@selector(sr) withObject:nil afterDelay:20];
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(sr)
                                           object:nil];
```

Please read the documentation. :) The documentation for [`-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a) points you to the methods for canceling a queued perform request.

Comment: Ice cold. I'm freezing now.

Comment: I put :) That should thaw you out a bit.