# How to have make a button disable a action (cocoa)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer, ibaction

I'm wondering if there is a way to disable a IBAction from a button. Basically I'm setting an NSTimer so that the application will close in 10 seconds in the applicationDidFinishLaunching, but when you push a button it will cancel that timer and the application will stay open. Is there any way to do this? Ive tried a very bad way and did a NSTimer when a NSButton (checkbox) was checked but when you push the button it would disable the checkbox and the timer. i want to know the programmatically way of doing this, thanks in advance.  (ON OS X COCOA)

Comment: I think `NSNotification` will work.

Comment: @Maappeal sorry but how?

Comment: Why not use something like [timer invalidate] in the IBAction method for your button.  This will remove the timer from the run loop.

Comment: @jwlaughton is correct.

Comment: @jwaughton thanks but I'm not exactly sure how to do that. I can't have the button invalidate a timer in the applicationDidFinishLaunching action, can i? Sorry but I'm a newbie at this. But i did get this:  [NSTimer ....] [button invalidate]; (that has to be in another action though)

Comment: Instead of using timers you could use `performSelectorAfterDelay` and when the button is clicked cancel it using `cancelpreviousrequest`. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055869/cancel-self-performselector-withobjectnil-afterdelay20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly, but you can disable button programmatically with

```
[myButton setEnabled:NO];
```

It will disable the button so it will be impossible to fire IBAction.

Or you can remove action from a button with

```
[myButton setAction:nil]
```

Comment: its close but i was wondering how to change a ibaction from a button meaning that the button would alter the code. i have a timer in applicationdidfinishlaunching and i want to disable that if the user enters the right password (using strings) and the button would disable that timer from another IBAction. sorry but I'm new to programming :|

Comment: You can change action for a button at any time:

- (IBAction)someAction1:(id)sender { .... }
- (IBAction)someAction2:(id)sender { .... }

[myButton setAction:@selector(someAction1:)]
[myButton setAction:@selector(someAction2:)]